# MVC3 boolean editor template with multiple controls for the same property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, zurb-foundation

I'm using c#, MVC3, Razor and Zurb Foundation 4.

I have a custom editor template for boolean values that will show different UI for different input devices. (visibility is controlled by Foundation's hide-for / show-for css classes)

The problem is that because all of these UI elements are always on the page, only the values in the first one will get bound to the model on post back.

So I either need to find a way of actually removing the HTML for the hidden divs or find a way to use a true value from any of the three elements (they all default to false so whichever is set to true would be the visible one)

This is my Boolean.cshtml:

```
@model bool

@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using Helpers

<div class="hide-for-small">
    <div class="hide-for-touch">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-for-small">
    <div class="hide-for-touch">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @{
                List<BoolString> ynb = new List<BoolString>();
                ynb.Add(new BoolString(false, "No"));
                ynb.Add(new BoolString(true, "Yes"));
            }
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model, new SelectList(ynb, "Value", "Description"))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-for-touch">
    <div class="switch round">
        <input id='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".Off"' name='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix' type='radio' checked />
        <label for='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".Off"' onclick=''>Off</label>

        <input id='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".On"' name='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix' type='radio' />
        <label for='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".On"' onclick=''>On</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently the checkbox works fine but the dropdown does not. (I always get false for my model property by the time I get back to the controller).
If I move the dropdown div before the checkbox then the dropdown works but the checkbox does not.

Note that I'm not sure about the touch element yet so it may be wrong anyway. I'm not bothered about getting that working until I have this problem sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cooked up a brute force apporach syncronizing each of the inputs using javascript & jquery. Please post if you find a better way

TEST FORM

```
@using BooleanEditorTemplate.Controllers
@model bool

@{ var modelname = "mmm"; }

@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home")){
<div class="hide-for-small">
    <div class="hide-for-touch">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.CheckBox(modelname, Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-for-small">
    <div class="hide-for-touch">
        <div class="editor-field">
            @{
                List<BoolString> ynb = new List<BoolString>();
                ynb.Add(new BoolString(false, "No"));
                ynb.Add(new BoolString(true, "Yes"));
            }
            @Html.DropDownList(modelname, new SelectList(ynb, "Value", "Description"))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-for-touch">
    <div class="switch round">
        <input id='@modelname' name='@modelname' type='radio' checked  value="on"/>
        <label for='@modelname' onclick=''>Off</label>

        <input id='@modelname' name='@modelname' type='radio' value="off"/>
        <label for='@modelname' onclick=''>On</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

TEST SCRIPT

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('[name="@modelname"]').change(
            function () {


                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var name = $(this).attr("name");                
                var checked = false;
                switch (this.type)
                {
                    case 'checkbox':
                        checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                        break;
                    case 'select-one':
                        checked = $(this).val().toUpperCase() == 'TRUE';
                        break;
                    case 'radio':
                        checked = $('input[type="radio"][name=' + name + ']:checked').val().toUpperCase() === 'ON';
                        break;
                }

                //checkbox
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', checked);

                //select the select-one
                if (checked)
                    $('select[name="' + name + '"]').val('True');
                else
                    $('select[name="' + name + '"]').val('False');

                //select the proper radio
                if (checked)
                    $('input[type="radio"][name='+ name +'][value="on"]').prop("checked", true);
                else
                    $('input[type="radio"][name=' + name + '][value="off"]').prop("checked", true);

            });
    });
</script>
```

and my test controler/classes setup

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index",true);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Boolean mmm)
    {
       return null;
    } 
}

public class BoolString
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BoolString(bool val, string desc)
    {
        this.Value = val;
        this.Description = desc;
    }
}
```

So this works on my box. I did have to make several modifications as I didn't test this within the editor framework. Undoutably, you'd have to make several more to adapt it back within the scope of your framework.

Comment: As you say, had to make a few tweaks. Nice idea though and it's all working now.